# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Buffer | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string; } | GetPublicKeyOrSecret'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jwt

**JWT Verification Code**
This is verification function to verify jwt using typescript.

```
public verify(
    token: string,
    secretOrPublicKey?: string | Buffer,
    options?: jwt.VerifyOptions
  ): Promise<object | string> {
    if (!secretOrPublicKey) {
      secretOrPublicKey = this.secretOrPublicKey;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jwt.verify(
        token,
        secretOrPublicKey,
        options,
        (err: jwt.VerifyErrors, decoded: object | string) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(decoded);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

And I found waring line on `secrectOrPublicKey` that is following and how to solve this please. Any comment would very helpful to me.

`(parameter) secretOrPublicKey: string | Buffer | undefined Argument of type 'string | Buffer | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Buffer | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string; } | GetPublicKeyOrSecret'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Buffer | { key: string | Buffer; passphrase: string; } | GetPublicKeyOrSecret'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 1):

When having this kind of issue just follow the types that the library uses https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jsonwebtoken/index.d.ts#L198

```
secretOrPublicKey: Secret | GetPublicKeyOrSecret,
```

`secretOrPublicKey` shouldn't be an optional parameter

Answer (score 0):

You've made sure that the value of `secretOrPublicKey` can't be `undefined` by doing this:

```
    if (!secretOrPublicKey) {
      secretOrPublicKey = this.secretOrPublicKey;
    }
```

But typescript assigned the type of `secretOrPublicKey` as `string | Buffer | undefined` because it was optional in the function arguments.  That type assignment doesn't get updated by your check.  Typescript still thinks it could be `undefined` and throws an error.

The easiest fix is to assign the default value in the function signature so that there is never a possibility that the value of `secretOrPublicKey` is set to `undefined`:

```
public verify(
    token: string,
    secretOrPublicKey: string | Buffer = this.secretOrPublicKey,
    options?: jwt.VerifyOptions
  ): Promise<object | string> {
```